# How does RoboGuice know what i mean to inject?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I am using RoboGuice 4.0beta2 , and i have this problem

I have several different objects that implement the same interface

call them 
A implements ITest
B implements ITest
C implements ITest

I have class D, that uses all 3 implementations together, each has a different purpose, but the same API for that

Inside class D i would like to inject A,B, and C, which have nothing to do with eachother,except the fact that they all implement the same interface

How would i configure the Module class to know that i mean different implementatios of ITest ?

Comment: Are you injecting A, B and C by their types or under the ITest type?

Comment: i want to inject it by ITest type

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the following configuration:

```
class D{
    @Inject ITest a;
    @Inject ITest b;
    @Inject ITest c;
}
```

you can set up your module like the following so you can inject the different types by `@Name`:

```
public class ABCModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ITest.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("a")).to(A.class);
        bind(ITest.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("b")).to(B.class);
        bind(ITest.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("c")).to(C.class);
    }
}
```

which allows you to inject the different types like so:

```
class D{
    @Inject @Named("a") ITest a;
    @Inject @Named("b") ITest b;
    @Inject @Named("c") ITest c;
}
```